# Pass query as a parameter?

Tags: sql-server-2017

I have created a user defined table type with a single varchar(max) column with the hopes that I could call my function by passing in an actual query. Of course it didn't work.

My function looks like this:

```
create function tfnTableToString(@strings TVP_Strings READONLY)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    return SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + string FROM @strings FOR XML PATH('')), 2 , 9999)
end
go
```

As you can see, I'm am just trying to make the code a little simpler by refactoring the process of converting query results into a comma delimited string. Is there a way to do this or am I just stuck having to write the ugly SUBSTRING(... FOR XML PATH...) wherever I need it?

Comment: what's the result of calling the funciton?

Comment: An error. I should have posted a little more info. I will update when I can get back to my computer.